# How to add colors to a string in typescript in angular 5

Tags: css, typescript, angular5

I am trying to display my data in Green color I tried with different methods but still it is not getting populated.

```
if(typeof(this._serverList)!="undefined"){
    var apparr=this._ApplicationList.find(x=>x.appNm==app);
    let strlist1=this._serverList.filter(i=>i.envId==envId&&i.appId==apparr.appId).map(x=>x.serverName);
    if(typeof(strlist1)!="undefined"){
        strlist1.forEach(line=>{
            if(line!="")
                line.fontcolor("green");  //HERE IS PROBLEM, NOT POPULATING
            list+='.'+line+'\n';
        });
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Would need to know what's happening with "list"... You have list+='.'+line+'\n'; so I can assume you end up with a string like: '.somestr\n.anotherstring\n.andanother\n'. So how do you plan on getting that into the DOM with styles? You'd have to split your string up and wrap each item in HTML with styles or something...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using the fontcolor() method - that's old and won't work in HTML5:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontcolor

If you are rendering the HTML properly from this string, then you should be able to easily achieve this by just assigning some hardcoded HTML to it (that's all fontcolor() does). So instead of doing line.fontcolor(color), you could just replace that line with:

```
line = '<p style="color: #000">' + line + '</p>
```

Or use template strings, etc.

```js
document.getElementById('red-text').innerHTML = '<p style="color: red">hello!</p>';
```

```html
<div id="red-text"></div>
```

Comment: No it is not what I want and I want that color should be assigned in type script file not in html. Moreover you tried in Javascript not in angular type script

Comment: I only provided a simple example to show an alternative to using fontcolor() method. You did not provide reproducible code, a plunker, etc. so I can't recreate your project.

I said in my description, replace in your code (in the typescript file) the line.fontcolor() with line = '<p style="color: red"> + line + </p>'

Comment: it is not still working give me your mail id i can send webex meeting to share my screen if you are okay with that.

Comment: Sorry, I'd rather not get that into it and your code but if you can do a simpler scenario in a plunker I'd be happy to take a look and play with it. There was a key point in my answer I think may apply to your issue now - "If you are rendering the HTML properly from this string" - that string is HTML and would have to be inserted into the DOM as HTML to be rendered (like using innerHTML).

You have this list that you are adding the string to and I have no idea what that is, how it ends up in the DOM, etc. - if you provide that I may be able to help more.

Comment: No I’m not rendering from html I’m getting data from Web api and displayed in html in mat-tooltip I have to add green color in web api or typescript file

Comment: I don't understand why you were using fontcolor() then - that just generates HTML so I presumed you had the rest tied up to be rendered. That is your main issue then.

Can you edit your question with the rest of the code to show how you get "line" in that loop and "list" that you add to, into the DOM? 

Color is going to come from the CSSOM/DOM so you have to get that string wrapped in HTML with style and in the DOM to get it green.

Need more code to help more...

Comment: My requirement is the data coming from Web api, I have to show in one color and the user what he enters from html(tool tip) should be in another color)

Comment: Everything I already said applies, you will need to use HTML/CSS to change the color - that seems to be the part you're not doing. You're just putting the data on the screen. You need to render HTML with style.